# Convert ASF file with codec Racal recorder to wav

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, sox

I want to convert the asf file which is having codec "A4;ACELP;;Racal Recorders".
Codec is detected using MediaInfo library. The file is not playable using any common audio/video players like VLC. Converting to wav using FFmpeg fails with error unknown codec.

Is there any converter/FFmpeg-plugin available for this codec?

*PS:I'm not able to share the file due to security policy*

Comment: Going to be difficult to help without a sample file.

Comment: Since media-info detected the codec, there should be some player or converter available?

Comment: Only if the player or converter has a demuxer and decoder that supports whatever formats this is.

Comment: Yes, my question is from where can I obtain the decoder of racal recorder. I can see lot of references to it when I do a wild search on Github. But no luck so far.

Comment: Unknown. I'm not yet sure what format the file is. `A4;ACELP;;Racal Recorders` is not very informative, so I don't  know what decoder can decode your mystery format. That is why a sample is needed to perform tests and to look at the file itself.

Comment: Have you tried the `sox` tool? It supports many audio formats. Not sure if your file has video+audio if it will work, so you may need to extract the audio first.

Comment: ffmpeg natively supports ACELP. try to update it or build your own version from master.

Comment: Already did that.